# Problem with py2app when FigureCanvasTkAgg is used in script

Tags: python, py2app

Python 3.9 on Mac running Big Sur:

I have a functioning script using tkinter that plots a dataframe on a figure canvas and that I want to convert to a Mac app using py2app. Here's the script, in which the user selects a .csv file and plots it:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from tkinter import Tk,filedialog,Menu

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("My App")
root.configure(bg='lightgrey')

### Function to determine all widgets open in window
def all_children (window) :
    _list = window.winfo_children()
    for item in _list :
        if item.winfo_children() :
            _list.extend(item.winfo_children())
    return _list

def _open():
    ### Close all open widgets
    widget_list = all_children(root)
    for item in widget_list:
        item.pack_forget()
    ### File dialog
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "Users/fishbacp/Desktop", title= 
    "Select file",filetypes = (("csv","*.csv"),("all files","*.*")))
    df=pd.read_csv(root.filename)

    fig = Figure() # create the figure
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)   # create the subplot
    df.plot(ax=ax)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP)#,fill='both',expand=True)

def _quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=_open)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=_quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

I followed the usual steps for py2app as given in the py2app documentation:

```
py2applet --make-setup MyApplication.py
rm -rf build dist
python setup.py py2app -A
```

I successfully ran the app from the terminal and then entered.

```
python setup.py py2app
```

The application was created, but when I double-clicked on it, a small error pop-up box appeared. The console provided no helpful information.

Because I've been able to incorporate simple matplotlib examples into apps, I feel I've isolated the problem to the following import statement.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
```

Is there something I can add to the setup.py file to address this? I've looked at the py2app documentation for customizing the setup file, but it's not clear how to include a particular function from the module.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to display some information when you run code - this way you may check which lines are executed and if variables have correct values. I don't use Mac but problem may be because tkinter is only wrapper or language `tcl` and its graphic module `tk` and it may need to add executable files `tcl`, `tk` to project.  The same problem was few days ago in other question. And this problem is in many other questions, also for WIndows and Linux.

Comment: The first step to debug issues like this is to start the application in the terminal, that is for MyApp.app run "dist/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp".  This will print errors to the terminal instead of that they'll be swallowed by the system.

This will likely print that some module or library cannot be found. You can use "includes" (modules) or "packages' (packages)  to explicitly include those missing modules/packages (but please report back, I can automate this in py2app).